# Get values from checkboxes without changing or updating

Tags: javascript, html

We are able to get values only if we update or recheck the checkboxes. It may be because of onchange event. Can you please help me with the code.

```
<input id="row1checkboxa1" type="checkbox" value="Reading" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this,'a',1,1)">
      Reading</p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="row1checkboxa2" value="wRiting" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this,'a',1,1)">
wRiting</p>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="row1checkboxa3" value="numeRacy" onchange="toggleCheckbox(this,'a',1,1)"> 
        numeRacy
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("row1checkboxa2").checked`

Comment: how to change input type="checkbox" statement to call toggleCheckbox with out calling onchange=

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `.checked` and `.value` to get the information of the element. Attaching sample code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" value="myvalue">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to display the value of the value attribute of the checkbox and boolean for whether the box is checked.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="value"></p>
<p id="isChecked"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  const value = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
  const isChecked = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = value;
  document.getElementById("isChecked").innerHTML = isChecked;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```